# Windows Automatic Sleep

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, sleep

At times I spend too much time nonstop online and forget to take a break. Is there any setting on my system so it goes to sleep every one hour even if it's not idle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this at desired interval (with task scheduler or anything else):

```
Rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep
```

Comment: This does not address "if it's not idle" part of the question

Comment: I read some articles to learn how to work with Task Scheduler, but I still don't know how to create Trigger(s). Should it be _At log on_, _At startup_, _On workstation unlock_, or do I need multiple triggers? Your further help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Mori - That sounds like a follow-up question honestly.  Honestly though only you can determine what triggers you require for this task to be helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound: You're right! I finally figured it out by creating two triggers — _At log on_ and _On workstation unlock_.

Answer (score -1):

I would use this to do it. It has adjustable configurations to let you do this. [image: TimeComX]

[TimeComX](http://www.bitdreamers.com/products/timecomx)

Comment: Why using extra software if Windows is already capable of doing such tasks?

Comment: This just seems like an advertisement for the program.  You don't indicate the reason you would use it.  It having "adjustable configurations" isn't really a reason.